# Excel VSTO Worksheet unique identifier

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I am looking for a way to create unique Worsksheet identifier, which would take into account at least name and content. If any worksheet value is changed then the identifier would change as well. I have checked the GetHashCode() but for some reason each time I call this method on the same sheet it always changes. Any ideas how to create that identifier/hash code

```
 Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
 var hash = sheet2.GetHashCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CodeName` of a worksheet *is* a unique identifier. VSTO uses the `CodeName` property for the internal name of the worksheet (probably Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.) when it creates a project with Worksheets in the Workbook.

In the VBA interface this property can be changed in the VBA IDE - it's the name used for the class module belonging to each Worksheet.

The property cannot be changed at run-time, only at design time. While the property may seem to reflect the caption for the worksheet (the name the user sees and can change in the UI), the two are *not* linked.

For more information, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately CodeName doesn't fulfill the second requirement, which is change if anything on the sheet is changed. I ended up to hash the content of the sheet. Any ideas why GetHashCode() changes each time I call it?

Comment: Why not use CodeName as the basis and increment a value concatenated to it?

Comment: For some reason when new workbook opened CodeName is empty.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information about your project *in your question" using the [edit] link.